# which event of trigger used to update field of child object?

Tags: trigger

I have two objects in which Parent is A and Child is B. My Trigger is on A then from that trigger i want to update field of B. In this scenario, which Event of Trigger achieve this?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend on your requirement. The only thing you need to think about is the trigger context. For example if you need to update child objects based on the Parent object update, you can use `after  update` trigger context.

[Context variable consideration](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) is the most important part for a trigger.

Go through [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) and try to understand the available trigger context variables and how to use them.

When you are implementing your own trigger, you may face problems and you will learn a lot with them. Very common issue that I have seen is trying to track `Id` in `before insert` triggers. It's obvious that there is no any `Id` available for a record before inserting it to the database.